# efficient way to calculate rolling median using pandas on irregular dataset with multiple occurences of same index

Tags: python, pandas

I have an irregular dataset where some indices show up multiple times and now want to calculate a floating median, once based on a timespan before the epoch, and once based on a timespan after the epoch.

Pandas `rolling` option would be good, however, it does not work well in case some indices occur multiple times...

I have written a function that does calculate my desired result. However, I suppose it is probably not the most efficient implementation and probably there is a more elegant solution using pandas directly.

Here is the code:
`fun` is my implementation based on the previous 2 days,
`fun2` is the same based on the next 2 days.
`rolling` tries to do the same but gives a different result in case some indices show up more often than once.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

def dummy_data():
    idx = np.array([pd.Timestamp(year=2021, month=1, day=1, hour=1),
                    pd.Timestamp(year=2021, month=1, day=2, hour=2),
                    pd.Timestamp(year=2021, month=1, day=3, hour=5),
                    pd.Timestamp(year=2021, month=1, day=3, hour=5),
                    pd.Timestamp(year=2021, month=1, day=3, hour=5),
                    pd.Timestamp(year=2021, month=1, day=8, hour=15),
                    pd.Timestamp(year=2021, month=1, day=9, hour=18),
                    pd.Timestamp(year=2021, month=1, day=10, hour=14),
                    ])
    data = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8])
    return pd.DataFrame(data, index=idx, columns=["l"])

def rolling_median_irregular(ds, left, right):
    res = pd.Series(index=ds.index, dtype=np.float64)
    for t in ds.index:
        val = ds.loc[(ds.index >= t - left) & (ds.index <= t + right)].median()
        res.loc[t] = val
    return res

if __name__ == "__main__":
    df = dummy_data()
    df["fun"] = rolling_median_irregular(df["l"], left=pd.Timedelta(days=2), right=pd.Timedelta(days=0))
    df["rolling"] = df["l"].rolling("2D").median()
    df["fun2"] = rolling_median_irregular(df["l"], left=pd.Timedelta(days=0), right=pd.Timedelta(days=2))
    df["rolling2"] = df.loc[::-1, 'l'].rolling("2D").median().loc[::-1]

    print(df.head(10))
```

The problem with `rolling` is that for the `2021-01-03` index, it will not work properly because it does not understand that this index shows up multiple times.
Compare the 3rd line. The correct median would be `3.5` because the timespan covers the values `[2 3 4 5]`. The `rolling` function lists `2.5` because it thinks the timespan only covers the values `[2 3]`.
At the 5th row, the `rolling` is correct because now it considers all `2021-01-03` data.

```
                     l  fun  rolling  fun2  rolling2
2021-01-01 01:00:00  1  1.0      1.0   1.5       1.5
2021-01-02 02:00:00  2  1.5      1.5   3.5       3.5
2021-01-03 05:00:00  3  3.5      2.5   4.0       4.0
2021-01-03 05:00:00  4  3.5      3.0   4.0       4.5
2021-01-03 05:00:00  5  3.5      3.5   4.0       5.0
2021-01-08 15:00:00  6  6.0      6.0   7.0       7.0
2021-01-09 18:00:00  7  6.5      6.5   7.5       7.5
2021-01-10 14:00:00  8  7.0      7.0   8.0       8.0
```

I would be looking for a better (faster/easier/more flexible) implementation of my `rolling_median_irregular` implementation.

It is not important if the outer edge (the one that is not the reference epoch) is included or not in the calculations because my data is irregular down to the millisecond thus there will *almost* never be the case that one epoch is directly at the edge.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `rolling` function, but you'll need to remove the "wrong" rows by using [`duplicated`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.duplicated.html) on the index, once using keep='last' and once 'first' depending on the direction of your rolling. Then thanks to index alignment, it populates the wanted value even for duplicates.

```
df['roll_test'] = df['l'].rolling("2D").median()[~df.index.duplicated(keep='last')]
df['roll_test2'] = (df.loc[::-1, 'l'].rolling("2D").median()
                      .loc[::-1][~df.index.duplicated(keep='first')])
print(df)
                     l  fun  rolling  fun2  rolling2  roll_test  roll_test2
2021-01-01 01:00:00  1  1.0      1.0   1.5       1.5        1.0         1.5
2021-01-02 02:00:00  2  1.5      1.5   3.5       3.5        1.5         3.5
2021-01-03 05:00:00  3  3.5      2.5   4.0       4.0        3.5         4.0
2021-01-03 05:00:00  4  3.5      3.0   4.0       4.5        3.5         4.0
2021-01-03 05:00:00  5  3.5      3.5   4.0       5.0        3.5         4.0
2021-01-08 15:00:00  6  6.0      6.0   7.0       7.0        6.0         7.0
2021-01-09 18:00:00  7  6.5      6.5   7.5       7.5        6.5         7.5
2021-01-10 14:00:00  8  7.0      7.0   8.0       8.0        7.0         8.0
```